# Winston logger different file for different date

Tags: node.js, winston, nosql

Does winston provide a way to write logs to different file when the date is changed?

**e.g.** errorLogs_10_04_2016.log, errorLogs_11_04_2016.log, errorLogs_12_04_2016.log

I need to export these logs, provide admin a way to export logs to a specific date.

**Update:**
As suggested by **krakig**, I tried using `DailyRotateFile` transport.

```
var winston = require('winston');

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({

            filename: 'logs.log',
            datePattern:'_dd-MM-yyyy'

        })
    ]
});
```

But I'm getting `winston.transports.DailyRotateFile is not a function` error.

My winston version is 2.2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature was added a while ago :

```
 winston.add(winston.transports.DailyRotateFile, {
      filename: './logs/my.log',
      datePattern: '.dd-MM-yyyy'
 });
```

EDIT :

I didn't mention it, but the package is independant. You have to get it from npm :

```
winston.transports.DailyRotateFile = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
```

Comment: I'm getting `winston.transports.DailyRotateFile is not a function` error

Comment: ahh thanks. i came across its npm page, but though that might be something else.

Comment: Its crashing when `maxFiles` is increased runtime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621662/winston-daily-rotate-crashes-if-maxfiles-is-increased-runtime